# How did World War I affect women in Italy?

Tags: italy, fascism, mussolini

I’m writing a paper on fascism and the ideology of women.  One of my topics I plan in discussing is World War I and how it impacted women both during and following the war.  I wanted to write 5 pages on this specific section and have trouble reaching the page count. I wrote about how it gave women unprecedented access to jobs they otherwise never had.  Then when the men came back from the war things reverted back to the ways of the past which showed Italy’s views on women.   Additionally, I mentioned how this showed mobilization and the importance of national unity. I need 2 more pages double spaced.  Can I get any suggestions on what else to talk about to fill the one count?

Comment: Things [didn't immediately revert back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feminism_in_Italy) to the ways of the past. In 1919 married women in Italy were granted separate economy, and public offices on lower levels were opened to women.

Comment: historyextra.com did an article on women's correspondence with Il Duce - might have something you could mine.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, is this it:: [Mussolini's willing followers](https://www.historyextra.com/period/second-world-war/mussolinis-willing-followers/)?

Comment: you can always try to look at how it affected women in spain during the rise of the spanish fascist movement "Falange", Phalanx, directly derived from the italian one.